# TBXML and XPath on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xml, ios, xpath

I've been looking for a good XML parsing library for my iPhone app and the [TBXML](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html) library was suggested [because it's the fastest.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project) However it doesn't appear to have support for XPath, which is unfortunate because that's the reason why I want to parse XML documents (actually, HTML documents parsed and searched as XML). **Are there any resources to make XPath available to TBXML, or what are some of the other fastest and most memory-conservative XML libraries for iPhone which support XPath queries?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath will alway be more expensive than the one you find.
**libxml2** looks good for what you want: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html